# Can I view the configuration from a specific build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

In Jenkins, is there any way I can view the configuration for a specific build?  I would like to see what the configuration looked like on a build that was successful once and then subsequently failed on being changed, but I don't know exactly what was changed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can check the configuration changes done to Jenkins job by using [Job History Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin). If you wanted to check changes done to the code, please check change set which would show the changes from last build. Below line in content section of Editable Email Notification will give the output of changes from the last build and changes from last successful build.

```
${CHANGES} 
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}
```